# unique_ptr assignment operator overload resolution

Tags: c++11, operator-overloading, move, unique-ptr, rvalue-reference

unique_ptr should be used with std::move semantics, and the copy assignment operator was explicitly removed for lvalues, so that anything like

```
unique_ptr<int> r = another_unique_ptr;
```

will not work.

I found the following signatures on [cpp reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D):

```
unique_ptr& operator=( unique_ptr&& r ); (1)    
template< class U, class E >
unique_ptr& operator=( unique_ptr<U,E>&& r ); (1)   
unique_ptr& operator=( nullptr_t );     (2)
```

The problem, however, is that

> The modifiable rvalue reference, Type&& , is willing to bind to
>   modifiable lvalues and modifiable rvalues

as stated [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/02/03/rvalue-references-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-2.aspx).

In the same article, section

> rvalue references: overload resolution

it's stated that

·         The initialization rules have veto power.

·         Lvalues strongly prefer binding to lvalue references, and rvalues strongly prefer binding to rvalue references.

·         Modifiable expressions weakly prefer binding to modifiable references.

No rule is going to prevent the lvalue to bind to the rvalue reference parameter in the signature. (it's just "strongly prefer", when there's no better alternative, the lvalue expression will bind to the rvalue function signature)

So, what's the point of having std::move, which essentially converts the lvalue expression to rvalue reference?

In an experiment, I tried

```
unique_ptr<SomeType> r = another_unique_ptr;
```

The error message is interesting, which confirms what I said above is wrong(but why???):

> error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp,
>   _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = ITreeNode; _Dp = std::default_delete >]’
>   typename ITreeNode::UniquePtr ptr = rootPtr;

It's looking for the function signature with lvalue reference. 
Is the visual cpp blog wrong about overload resolution involving rvalue reference? Or is it because I'm using g++ 4.8.2 and its behavior is different from the vc++ compiler? Then which compiler gives the correct/intended behavior?

Please enlighten me!

Comment: That 2009 blog entry is horrendously out of date. Don't rely on it. Rvalue references do not bind to reference-related lvalues.

Comment: yup, I was suspecting the same thing, but not confident enough to make that assertion. Cheers.